# What is the type constructor for list of tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples, type-constructor

### The question

What is the *type constructor* which generates a *concrete type* like `[(Int,String)]`?

### The origin of the question

I think this really sounds either like a stupid question or a meaningless riddle. I hope the following convinces you that I'm actually trying to find gaps in my understanding of the basics.

I know that `[]`

- is a *value* (an empty list of any type),
- and it is a (unary) *type constructor*;

to "visualize" the second aspect, I can just type

```
> x = [1,2,3] :: [] Int
> :t x
x :: [Int]
```

which clearly shows that `[]` applied to the concrete type `Int` gives another concrete type `[Int]`.

So far so good.

On the other hand, `(,)` also has two meanings:

- it is a (binary) *type constructor* too, which I verify with this

```
> x = (1,1) :: (,) Int Int
> :t
x :: (Int, Int)
```

- but it is also a *value constructor*:

```
> (,) 1 "hello"
(1,"hello")
```

So, if both `[]` and `(,)` are type constructors that can originate, among other types, concrete types `[Int]` and `(Int,Char)`, I wonder what is the type constructor that generates a type like `[(Int,Char)]`.

Comment: _Needs more focus_? Really. Enlighten me about why this is the case... :)

Comment: "`[]` applied to the concrete type `Int` gives another concrete type `[Int]`" yes: try `GHCi> :k []` in GHCi to see this type's *kind* attesting to that. use `GHCi> :t []` to see that *value*'s *type* (same with `(,)`, both as a value and as a type -- functions are values too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much a single type constructor as it is a nested type constructor:

```hs
λ> x = [(1, 'a')] :: [] ((,) Int Char)
λ> :t x
x :: [(Int, Char)]
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to see in your code something akin to a `g (f x)` that could be written as `g . f $ x`... Is this the case?

Comment: For ~~reasons~~, you can't do that. `type LP x y = [] ((,) x y)` gets close, but does not define `type LP :: Type -> Type -> Type`. You just get `type LP (x :: Type) (y :: Type) :: Type`. Basically, allowing "arbitrary code" in types makes type inference impossible, so strong restrictions are put in place on how types can be formed. With a defunctionalization approach, as in `singletons` (see `Apply` and `.@#@$$$` and friends), you can "go left" and choose complex types over type inference, but that's not a sensible default for a general purpose language right now.

Comment: Also note that in your analogy it's not actually `f (g x)`, but rather `f (g x y)`, which cannot be rephrased as `f . g $ x y`

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, there is `Data.Functor.Compose`, so you could say, for example, `Compose [] ((,) Int) Char`.  But it's only equivalent up to `newtype` constructors, which can be cumbersome.  `Compose` is useful if you're going on to use the compositional structure somehow  (e.g. the composition of applicative functors is applicative), but it's definitely not worth it if you're just doing it for notation's sake.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit form of such a type constructor but you can roll your own:

```
type TupleList f s = [(f, s)]
```

`TupleList` is now a type constructor with two argument. If you apply it to the types `Int` and `Char` it constructs a type `TupleList Int Char`, which is synonymous to `[(Int, Char)]`:

```
tupleList :: TupleList Int Char
tupleList = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```